# How to access control inside Gridview OnRowDataBound and Gridview inside Repeater control

Tags: asp.net, gridview, repeater

I want to find lblTitle control in GridView OnRowDataBound, and gridview is in the Repeater control. Can you please help? Thank  you.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="parentRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="OnItemDataBound" >
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="childRepeater" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="BookID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                                   
                     <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server"  ></asp:Label>

                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                                         
             </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

</asp:Repeater>

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        GridView childRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("childRepeater") as GridView;
        Label lblTotal = childRepeater.FooterRow.FindControl("lblTotal") as Label;
        lblTotal.Text = childRepeater.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
}
```